# Vuex state change on object does not trigger rerender

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a variable in the vuex store called permissions. And i want my component to trigger a rerender when the getPermissions changes. In the vue devtools i clearly see that the state has changed in the store, but the component stil get the old state from getPermissions. In order for me to see changes, I have to do a refresh. Has it something to do with the way i mutate it? or the fact that it is an object?

It looks like this when populated:

```
permissions: { 
    KS1KD933KD: true,
    KD9L22F732: false
}
```

I use this method to do mutations on it and a getter to get it:

```
const getters = {
  getPermissions: state => state.permissions
};

const mutations = {
  set_recording_permissions(state, data) {
    let newList = state.permissions;
    newList[data.key] = data.bool;
    Vue.set(state, 'permissions', newList);
  }
};
```

And in the component i use mapGetters to get access to it

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('agentInfo',['getPermissions'])
  }
```

In order to update the permissions value i use this action (it does require a succesfull api request before updating the value) :

```
const actions = {
  async setRecordingPermissions({ commit }, data) {
    let body = {
      agentId: data.userName,
      callId: data.callId,
      allowUseOfRecording: data.allowUseOfRecording
    };
    try {
      await AgentInfoAPI.editRecordingPermissions(body).then(() => {
        commit('set_recording_permissions', { key: data.callId, bool: data.allowUseOfRecording });
        commit('set_agent_info_message', {
          type: 'success',
          text: `Endret opptaksrettigheter`
        });
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      commit('set_agent_info_message', {
        type: 'error',
        text: `Request to ${error.response.data.path} failed with ${error.response.status} ${error.response.data.message}`
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: .shouldn't it be: ..mapGetters(['agentInfo','getPermissions'])

Comment: no, i have different modules, in this case this means: get getter "getPermissions" from module agentInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the getter only returns state variable you should use mapState, if you want to access it directly.

```
computed: mapState(['permissions'])
```

However, you can also use mapGetters, but then in your template, have to use `getPermissions` and not `permissions`. 
Example template:

```
<ul id="permissions">
  <li v-for="permission in getPermissions">
    {{ permission }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you have done this it is probably an issue with the object reference. You use `Vue.set`, but you set the same object reference. You have to create a new object or set the key you want to update directly.

**new object**

```
let newList = { ...state.permissions };
```

**Vue.set**

```
Vue.set(state.permission, data.key, data.value);
```

Comment: I've already tried to use mapState, with the same results. Currently in my template i use getPermission in this maner: if(getPermissions[id]){console.log('hi)}

Comment: you should post your template, your vuex store and the component seperated

Comment: my files are a bit complicated and big. May also contain sensitive data that i dont wanna show. So i've simplified it alot

Comment: your problem is probably related to reactivity. use Vue.set directly on the added property or copy object by using spread operator normally solves it.

Comment: Ahh thanks, yeah i needed to use the spread operator when i copied my value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rest of you code looks like, but you will need to use actions to correctly mutate you store.

For example:

```
const actions = {
  setName({ commit }, name) {
    commit('setName', name);
  },
}
```